# PartCover browser not opening code files

Tags: partcover

We're generating PartCover reports via the command line tool along with our CruiseControl.Net unit tests. This generates an xml file that displays the results nicely  on the cruisecontrol dashboard. The xslt transforms that are included only show you the percentage of coverage in an individual class. We want to know exactly what lines are not being covered. The problem ist when we open the report in the PartCover browser and double click a method it doesn't show us our cs files. I know the PartCover browser is capable of showing you the files because of the following.

Here's a screenshot of PartCover browser with the lines of code showing: http://kjkpub.s3.amazonaws.com/blog/img/partcover-browse.png.

The information looks like it should be available to the browser because the report contains this:

`<Method name="get_DeviceType" sig="Cathexis.IDBlue.DeviceType  ()" bodysize="19" flags="0" iflags="0">
   <pt visit="2" pos="0" len="1" fid="82" sl="35" sc="13" el="35" ec="14" />
   <pt visit="2" pos="1" len="4" fid="82" sl="36" sc="17" el="36" ec="39" />
   <pt visit="2" pos="5" len="2" fid="82" sl="37" sc="13" el="37" ec="14" />
</Method>`

and this:

`<File id="66" url="D:\sandbox\idblue\idblue\trunk\software\code\driver\dotnet\Common\AsyncEventQueue.cs" />`

All I want to be able to do is view what lines of code are not being covered in my test cases without having to figure out what the xml above is trying to tell me.

Thanks to anyone in advance who replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out why the cs files were not displaying. The paths were incorrect in the xml file because our test project was being built on a different machine than the one partcover was on. (partcover must generate the .cs file paths from pdb files maybe?) Once I search and replaced the file switching the base directory of our subversion location to the one on the other machine all was well.